# Editing Table design in response to Javascript enable/disable

Tags: javascript, html-table

If I had a HTML table that had three rows of 4 cells each and I wanted to change the number of cells in the third row depending on whether a script is available.  My main goal is to change the position of my menu.  The reason is that if Javascript is disabled, I would like the 2nd cell of the second row to be filled with a simple menu that doesn't have any drop down menus and is old school running from top to bottom.  If the user has Javascript I would like the page to use a Javascript menubar ontop that runs left to right with all the bells and whistles.  The second cell on the 2nd row contains page content but if Javascript is enabled and I don't need the old-school menu on the left then I want the content to occupy both the second row cells to remove a space where the menu would have gone.

I have tried using `<script><noscript>` tags when creating the second row as follows:

```
    <Noscript>
        <TR> 
            <TD></TD>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD></TD> 
            <TD></TD>
        </TR>
    </noscript>

    <Script> 
        <TR> 
            <TD></TD>
            <TD colspan=2></TD>
            <TD></TD>  
        </TR>
    </script>
```

When I disable Javascript it gives what is expected but when I enable Javascript I get a syntax error probably because this isn't the way to do it.  The entire existing website was done on a table and changing the layout method isn't really my first choice.  Does anyone have any experience with doing this or perhaps a solution to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're after but here goes...

I'd suggest putting a different class on both TRs (The one that should only be displayed if JavaScript is enabled and the default one) and setting the one which should only displayed if JS is enabled to "display: none" in your css.

If JavaScript is enabled simply set that TR to "display: block" (or static maybe) and the other one (the default one) to "display: none".